# Закрыть все View - Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Создал динамически на странцие много itemView.
Как логически понять сколько view открыто (itemView) и закрыть их?

```
define([
"app",
"text!templates/masterhome/homepage.html",

"collections/ItemhomeCollection",

"views/masterhome/homepage/itemhomeView",

"parsley"], function(app, homepageTemplate, ItemhomeCollection, ItemhomeView){


var homepageView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'main_window',
    
    template: _.template(homepageTemplate),

    events: {

    },

    // Инициализация homepage.
    // 1. Загружаем глобальную коллекцию ItemhomeCollection
    // 2. ItemhomeCollection.fetch().

    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this);

        app.collectionItemhome = new ItemhomeCollection();
        app.collectionItemhome.fetch({
            reset:true,
            success: function() {
                if(DEBUG) console.log('COLLECTION ITEMHOME:: ' + _.size(app.collectionItemhome) )
            }
        });

        if (_.size(app.collectionItemhome) > 0) this.renderAll();

        this.listenTo(app.collectionItemhome, 'add', this.renderOne);
        this.listenTo(app.collectionItemhome, 'reset', this.renderAll);
    },

    renderOne: function(item) {
        
        this.itemhomeView = new ItemhomeView({ model:item })
          
        if (item.get('status') == 1 || item.get('status') == 2) $('.mh-active-items').append(this.itemhomeView.render().$el); 
        if (item.get('status') == 3 || item.get('status') == 4) $('.mh-old-items').append(this.itemhomeView.render().$el); 
           
        return this;
    },

    renderAll: function() {
        app.collectionItemhome.each(function(item){
            this.renderOne(item);
        }, this);
    },

    render:function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template({}));
        return this;
    },
    remove: function() {
        
      this.el.remove();
      this.stopListening();
      return this;    

    }
```

//

> При инициализации я загружаю коллекцию и делаю fetch()
>
> Так как в опциях fetch я указал **reset:true**, срабатывает метод
> **renderAll** котороый циклично прогоняет коллекцию и вызывает для каждой модели коллекции метод renderOne()
>
> В методе renderOne создается переменная **this.itemhomeView** как
> экземпляр вида ItemhomeView.
>
> Так как основных видов у меня несколько. При закрытии этого -
> основного мне нужно закрыть все созданные ItemhomeView. **Как я могу это
> сделать?**
>
> Если в методе remove я вызываю this.itemhomeView.remove();
>
> То закрываю **только последний** созданный ItemhomeView

Comment: Стройте иерархию видов, привязывая дочерние view к родительским. Закрытие при таком подходе - тривиальная рекурсивная процедура.

Comment: А еще, советую вам посмотреть в сторону http://marionettejs.com/ =)

Comment: Спасибо, я думаю о marionette в будущем)

Comment: Просто в этом фреймворке вся возня с видами, которой не хватает в Backbone, уже реализована

Comment: Да, читал об этом)
На самом деле хочется хорошо освоить сам backbone.js - по этому и пишу на чистом. Я и не сомневаюсь что перейду на marionette

Answer (score 1):

В общем сделал так.

При инициализации создаю пустой массив для элементов.
В методе renderOne после добавления его в видимость я добавляю его в массив.
В методе remove - сканирую массив и удаляю каждый view.
Других вариантов пока в голове нет))